# Android: How to listen to MouseEvent on other View, and handle the event in my custom view

Tags: android, tooltip, mouseevent

For practicing purpose, I am create a customized Tooltip control. To use the Tooltip control, a hosting UIControl (e.g. a `Button`) will be assigned to my Tooltip control, and I want my Tooltip control is be able to listen to the mouse press event on the hosting control (i.e. the `Button`), and show / dismiss itself accordingly.

I am having problem finding a way to listening to mouse events of the hosting control.  I tried:

1. Set the Hosting Control's `setOnTouchListener`, this works, but it will override the existing `OnTouchListener` of the Hosting Control, thus undeserable.
2. Go to the Hosting Control's `ViewGroup`, and add a **Observer to the `ViewGroup`.  But there is no way to observe the mouse event on the `ViewGroup`.

So is listening to other control's mouse event doable from a custom view, if so, what's the recommended way to implement it ?

Thanks.

---

I also thought of another way to do it, as followed:

1. Get the `ViewGroup` of the hosting control;
2. In the `ViewGroup`, add a transparent view to listen to the mouse event.
3. In the handler of mouse event of the transparent view, check whether the mouse event is happened on the Hosting Control.
4. If happened on the Hosting Control, respond correspondingly.

I will try this approach after I post my question, but it seems to be resource-intensive way of implementing something seemingly straightforward.

I will let you know if this approach works or not, any comment / thought is very appreciated.

Thanks ~!

Comment: As I understand you have a custom button that already have custom OnTouchListener. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this approach. I've already tried this approach with `OnClickListener` and it works great.

```
  public class CustomButton extends Button {

      private OnTouchListener outsideListener;

      private OnTouchListener innerListener = new OnTouchListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
              if (outsideListener != null) {
                  outsideListener.onTouch(v, event);
              }
              //some code here ...
          }
      };

      @Override
      public void setOnTouchListener(OnTouchListener listener) {
          outsideListener = listener;
      }

      public CustomButton(Context context) {
          super(context);
          super.setOnTouchListener(innerListener);
      }

      public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
          super(context, attrs);
          super.setOnTouchListener(innerListener);
      }

      public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
          super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
          super.setOnTouchListener(innerListener);
      }
  }
```

Comment: Hi Sazanvoich, thanks for your reply.

Maybe I didn't explained myself well.  I am implementing a custom ToolTip control.  To use my ToolTip, other developer only need to specify which control that my ToolTip control will attached to.  Then my ToolTip control will handle the rest, without requiring their control to be written in a certain way.

Answer (score 0):

as I mentioned in my question, I thought of a way to implement what I wanted.  I am sharing my way of implementing here. But still, it seems to be resource-intensive way of solving seemingly simple problem.  If you have an easier solution, or any comment, please leave a comment. Much Appreciated ~!

My custom MaterialTooltip class:

```
public class MaterialToolTip {
   /// Implementation
}
```

An example of how to use my MaterialToolTip class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   MaterialToolTip toolTip;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       // anchorButton is the button to which ToolTip will be added to.
       Button anchorButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);            


       this.toolTip = new MaterialToolTip.Builder(this)
            //.anchorView property is used to specify the view that will use this tooltip
            .anchorView(anchorButton)  
            .maxWidth(R.dimen.simpletooltip_max_width)
            .build();  // that's all the consumer needs to do, as soon as the tooltip is attached to the View, the tooltip decided when to show / dismiss by listening to View's event.
   }
}
```

Within my MaterialToolTip class:

1. Create a transparent view that listens to mouse event

   ```
   @SuppressLint("ViewConstructor")
   public class ToolTipPressInterceptView extends View {

       OnAnchorViewMouseEventListener mListener;

       ToolTipPressInterceptView(Context context, View anchorView) {
         super(context);

       //get the anchorView's onScreenLocation
       int[] output = new int[2];
       anchorView.getLocationOnScreen(output);

       anchorViewRect = new RectF(output[0], output[1], output[0] + anchorView.getMeasuredWidth(), output[1] + anchorView.getMeasuredHeight()) ;

       //set the dimension to match parent
       this.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
       this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
               switch (event.getAction()){
                   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
                       if (anchorViewRect.contains(event.getX(), event.getY())){
                           mListener.onMouseEvent(AnchorViewMouseEventType.PRESSED);
                       }
                   }
                   case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{
                       if (anchorViewRect.contains(event.getX(), event.getY())){
                           mListener.onMouseEvent(AnchorViewMouseEventType.RELEASED);
                       }
                   }
               }
               return false;
           }
       });
   }

   }
   ```
2. Get the ViewGroup of the hosting control, and add the transparent view to the ViewGroup;

   private MaterialToolTip(Builder builder){
           //.. Other initialisation logic
          //.. add the TransparentView to the ViewGroup;
          mRootView = (ViewGroup)mAnchorView.getRootView();
         ToolTipPressInterceptView view = new ToolTipPressInterceptView(mContext, mAnchorView);

   ```
     //mAnchorViewTouchListener is listener to Mouse Event   
       view.setOnTouchListener(mAnchorViewTouchListener);
       mRootView.addView(view);
   ```

   }
3. If happened on the Hosting Control, respond correspondingly.

   private final View.OnTouchListener mAnchorViewTouchListener = new

   View.OnTouchListener(){
           @Override
           public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
               int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

   ```
           switch(action) {
               case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) :
                   // show
                   show();
               case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) :
                   // dismiss
                   dismiss();
           }

           return false; //return false so the other handlers is able to
       }
   };
   ```